# How to make my web application working with SPDY, Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, spdy

I have a simple web application in a dynamic project in eclipse, it contains only a html page and a http servlet. Until now I have always used tomcat. Tomcat's SPDY support is not usable in its current form, so i have to move my application to Jetty. 
To make my application working with spdy, i have to re-write my application or i have only to configure jetty to work with spdy?
Could you help me please?

UPDATE: I have my HTTP/1.1 application in .war file and i copy this file from tomcat/webapps in my-9.2.x-jetty-distribution/webapps, i strated jetty and it works as expected. To make this application working with spdy, i have to run jvm with npn-boot and then i have to configure xml files as documentation describes, but not say where these xml files have to be placed. My problem is in these two last steps.

Comment: You're aware that [SPDY is deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) in favor of HTTP/2, right?

Comment: I know it very well, however i have to use spdy.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change a single line in your webapp, assuming it's written against standard APIs.

In order to make it work in Jetty, you just need to follow the instructions in the [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/spdy.html).

You need at least JDK 7 and Jetty 9.2.x.

The Jetty Project has removed support for SPDY in Jetty 9.3.x, in favour of HTTP/2, but if you need to use SPDY you can stay on Jetty 9.2.x.

I would consider to move directly to HTTP/2, however. Browsers like Firefox and soon Chrome already default at using HTTP/2, so SPDY will have a very short life (in fact, it is being phased out already).

Comment: Thank you @sbordet ,i discover jetty today. I read this documentation all the day, however i don't know how to use these xml files. I also have a problem to run npn-boot: "java -Xbootclasspath/p: C:\npn-boot-1.1.8.v20141013.jar", i downloaded the right version that corresponds to my jdk. The documentation describes well the xml files but does not say where to place them.

Comment: @david6630 be sure you are using an Oracle Java release, not OpenJDK if you intend on using npn or alpn.

Comment: @joakim Erdfelt I'm using an oracle java release, jdk update 67.

Comment: @david6630 please read the section about [how to start Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html) and the section about how to [deploy your webapp](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-deployment.html). That should be enough to get you started.